# Columns in Bootstrap not responsive in Firefox with float: none

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center content of columns in bootstrap 3 using cs like this:

```
.row{
padding: 40px 0px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
display:table;
height: 100%;
position:relative;

}


@media (min-width: 1200px)
{
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-8 {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
float: none;
}

}

@media (min-width: 992px)
{
.col-md-6, 
.col-md-4, 
.col-md-8 {
float: none; 
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;

}
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fill">      

<div class="row" id="section-0">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<h1>Webtoaster</h1>
<p>some text  </p> 
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
<img src="img/koko.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="section-1">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8"><img src="img/fista.png" class="img-responsive" >
</div>
</div>
```

The above code does center vertically but in Firefox my image is not responsive anymore, and does not scale on resizing window.
It does resize in chrome and Safari however when i resize to a very small screen it does not put the image underneath the text. This problem is caused by float: none; if I comment it all responsiveness works well.
Example of page here: http://jajko.byethost16.com
Please help

Comment: #1 rule when using a grid system - DO NOT MODIFY THE BASE GRID CSS. .row is not a table in bootstrap, so don't make it a `display:table` in your CSS. There's a hundred things wrong with the CSS you posted, so the easiest way to fix it is to use Bootstrap the way it was intended - not by modifying it's CSS, but by using it's classes.

Comment: `text-align:center` remove `float`

Comment: I have no clue which of the bootstrap default classes will vertically center my text.

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam said, don't modify grid. Just place a div inside your col div and give to it display: table, height: 100% and inside that place another div with display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle.

Comment: I know I should not modify the grid. I've tried some divs nested inside col div but it does not work at all

Comment: Sorted by adding 

    .img-responsive{width:100%;

    }
Probably modifying grid is not a best approach, but it works fine !